# How to combine multiple UPDATE statement in one query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$conn->query("UPDATE users SET totalClicks = totalClicks + 1 WHERE id = '$uid'");


$conn->query("UPDATE link SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE userid = '$uid' AND id = '$id'");


$conn->query("UPDATE data SET total_actions_3 = total_actions_3 + 1");
```

I want to put all these 3 queries into one prepared statement, how to do that ?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: These are three different tables you're updating. Why not keep it that way and wrap them in a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`?

Comment: Try considering using a mysql stored procedure. But it's not a good idea to place business logic on database always.

Comment: tadman, don't be scared, I am already updating all my scripts with mysqli_escape_sting and prepare, and bind_param and bind_result and all that... :D

Answer (score 0):

Combining them is not a good idea. Keep them the way they are.